# Create list from input

Tags: python, list, input

So, I have an input like below

```
result = input("What was the result?")
```

The point is that the user will answer in the form `"1-1"`, or `"120-100"`

My problem is I want to use the information that is given and therefore have to get rid of the dash and create a list for instance. Would it be possible to get a list in this form?

`["120", "100"]` (achieving to exclude the bracket)

Comment: Your question appears to be *"can text be parsed?"*, in which case the answer is: yes.

Comment: btw you mean 'hyphen' or 'dash' (I hear the grammar police arriving) rather than 'bracket' I think.  May be confusing to people reading your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
result.split('-')
```

Comment: @diaco: well this is Python after all

Comment: You will also need to use raw_input instead of input for this to work in python 2.x.

Comment: @garnertb: Assuming OP is using Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x `raw_input()` has been renamed `input()`.

Comment: @diaco: btw I feel crass for asking, but are you aware of the "Accept Answer" thing to the left?

Comment: If I wasn't Before, then now I am! :)

Comment: @diaco: hmm... you don't appear to have accepted answers to any of your questions to date.  Perhaps you're clicking on the wrong thing?  See [this document](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for details.

Comment: sorry, now I did! haha I'm pretty new here still learning some things